# Database design for grouping

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a system that receive alerts(traffic, robbery,...), of which several belong to the same event(that is told from different sources), but the event is the same, so i should be able to group them and like twitter just show one with the option to see the others(in twitter:see conversation), my doubt is with the design of this relation, with id_alert_f being the father(the first) and the others grouped under it, those id_alert_c (child)

table alert

```
   id_alert, message, date, id_category, id_location
```

table event

```
   id_event, id_alert_f
```

table events_alert

```
   id_alert_f, id_alert_c
```

is this design going to be able to support correctly that end?

Comment: Shouldn't event -> alert be a 1:n relationship?

Comment: that's correct, one event many alerts, but one event only one alert_father(the very first) grouping the rest of alerts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the events_alert table, this would only be needed if alert and event is a n:n relation.

event
------
id_event

alert
------
id_alert
id_event
message
date
id_category
id_location

id_alert_f could be added to event, could also be retreived with a order by min date [to get the first], or a boolean in the alert as is_father